# How to validate mime type of image in a Model in SpringMVC with Annotation?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, arrays, mime-types

I have this Model in my Application and I upload a image/svg+xml to my Server:

```
public class ImageModel{

    private Integer Id;

    @NotEmpty
    @Pattern(regexp = "^[a-zA-Z0-9äöüÄÖÜ\\d\\-_\\s]+$")
    private String name;

    //here some annotation to check the mimetype of this byte array
    private byte[] data;
 }
```

Is there a way to validate the mime type of the field data, here directly in my Model with annotations?

Comment: Mime type of byte array? What exactly you mean?

Comment: I upload my image from my html formular as a byte array.

Comment: have u tried using the `@Consumes` annotation? see: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/gipzh/index.html

Comment: thx mr. @Ronin but I couldn't use that annotation - It is unknown - I tried to import the lib, but it couldn't be resolved. I'm so sorry. but anyways - thx for nothing.

Comment: @user3037960 have u tried turning java off and turning .NET on again?

Comment: @Ronin hahahahahahahaha

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a solution for the Model @Annotations, I solved it by doing the validation check in my controller:

```
     InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(myByteArray));
            String mimeType = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromStream(is);

            if ( mimeType == null){
                result.addError(new ObjectError("file", "Only SVG allowed!"));
            }else if(mimeType != null && !mimeType.equalsIgnoreCase("application/xml")){
                result.addError(new ObjectError("file", "Sorry Bro, only SVG allowed!"));
            }
 if (result.hasErrors()) {
            // send back to edit form
            model.addAttribute("uploadForm", data);
            return "image/editPage";
        }
```